# Spring multi level url mapping inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have following user controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private static final String ID = "id";

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private UserManager um;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserManager(UserManager userManager) {
        this.um = userManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = null;

        String id = (String) request.getParameter(ID);
        if (id == null) {
            String message = "Cannot find user id";
            logger.error(message);
            return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp", "message", message);
        }
        try {
            user = (User) um.getUserByUserId(Integer.parseInt(id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String message = "Cannot find user with id: " + id;
            logger.error(message);
            return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp", "message", message);
        }

        logger.info("Returning user view for user id: " + id);
        return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/user.jsp", "user", user);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getNewUserForm(Model model) {
        logger.info("Get new user form");
        return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/userForm.jsp", "user", new User());
    }
```

all my views files are in WEB-INF/jsp/

When i try go to page: localhost:8080/myapp/user.htm everything works fine but when i try go to: localhost:8080/myapp/user/new.htm I get error 404 page not found.

Whats more this code is executed because i see logs:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getNewUserForm(Model model) {
            logger.info("Get new user form");
            return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/userForm.jsp", "user", new User());
        }
```

On 404 error page is information:
/myapp/user/WEB-INF/userForm.jsp not foud

And here is my problem. How to change this to: /myapp/WEB-INF/userForm.jsp ? What should I do with my request mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Spring [Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments) about controllers and return types.
There are great examples there, and you can see the many ways you can use a controller method.

In your case, you don't need to specify the full path to your view. Just the view name is ok.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getNewUserForm(Model model) {
    logger.info("Get new user form");

    return new ModelAndView("userForm", "user", new User());
}
```

You can even do it this way. Spring allows for many possibilities. The documentation outlines all of this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getNewUserForm(Model model) {
    logger.info("Get new user form");
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "userForm";
}
```

Also, make sure you have your [View Resolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver) configured.
You can see from the documentation that you will need something like this.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You are right but your solution is not working :/

When I return only view name server is looking for views in folder: /myapp/user/userForm
in my case: /myapp/user/WEB-INF/userForm
but I need: /myapp/WEB-INF/userForm

How to configure this?

Comment: Solution was very easy :/

In my case to resolve correct views only by name I needed define new view resolver bean in dispatcher servlet xml file.


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

Comment: @NorbertPabian, there's still a little more to do to accept an answer, you need to click on the check mark on the left side of the answer to formally accept. Also see [how accepting an answer works](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Cheers :)